# javascript elements/tags array DOM node access

Tags: javascript, arrays, text

what's the different between using:

```
// assuming using elements/tags 'span' creates an array and want to access its first node

1) var arrayAccess = document.getElementsByTagName('elementName')[0]; // also tried property items()
```

**vs**

```
// assuming I assign an id value to the first span element/tag  
// specifically calling a node by using it's id value    

2) var idAccess = document.getElementById('idValue');
```

---

then if I want to change the text node....when using example 1) it will not work, for example:

```
arrayAccess.firstChild.nodeValue = 'some text';
```

or

```
arrayAccess.innerText/innerHTML/textContent = 'some text';
```

If I "access" the node through its id value then it seems to work fine....

Why is it that when using array it does not work?  I'm new to javascript and the book I'm reading does not provide an answer.

Comment: When all else fails, there is always the specification: [*getElementById*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId), [*getElementsByTagName*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-A6C9094). Note that *getElementsByTagName* returns a [*NodeList*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-536297177), **not** an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are working,

In your first case you need to pass the tag name instead of the element name. Then only it will work.

There might be a case that you trying to set input/form elements using innerHTML. At that moment you need to use .value instead of innerHTML.
InnerHTML should be used for div, span, td and similar elements.

So your html markup example:

```
<div class="test">test</div>
<div class="test">test1</div>
<span id="test">test2</span>

<button id="abc" onclick="renderEle();">Change Text</button>
```

Your JS code:

```
function renderEle() {
    var arrayAccess = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
    arrayAccess.innerHTML = "changed Text";
    var idEle = document.getElementById('test');
    idEle.innerHTML = "changed this one as well";
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4srucr1L/)

Comment: Thanks, you are right it works! Apparently chrome does not function well using NodeList.  I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

When you use document.getElementsByTagName('p'), the browser traverses the rendered DOM tree and returns a node list (array) of all elements that have the matching tag.

When you use document.getElementById('something'), the browser traverses the rendered DOM tree and returns a single node matching the ID if it exists (since html ID's are unique).

There are many differences when to use which, but one main factor will be speed (getElementById is much faster since you're only searching for 1 item).

To address your other question, you already have specified that you want the first element in the returned nodeList (index [0]) in your function call:

```
var arrayAccess = document.getElementsByTagName('elementName')[0];
```

Therefore, arrayAccess is already set to the first element in the returned query.  You should be able to access the text by the following.  The same code should work if you used document.getElementById to get the DOM element:

```
console.log(arrayAccess.textContent);
```

Here's a fiddle with an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/qoe30w2w/

Hope this helps!

Comment: browser incompatibility....chrome was not working but firefox runs without a problem...wasn't expecting this...I thought chrome would be able to handle it. This is the same exact code I'm working on : http://jsfiddle.net/1Lpz0a7d/9/

Comment: I've run into browser incompatibilities using tag name, but more so w/ IE.  I pulled out the code from the function and it seems to work fine in latest chrome.: </br></br>var nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
        alert(nodeList);

Comment: well I'm using Aptana 3 IDE, but I doubt this has anything to do with the issue...I also have the latest chrome version running..

Comment: Actually, your code (using tag name) is running fine in your fiddle on chrome when user name length < 5.

Comment: Yes, I'm running the fiddle sample on chrome and it works fine but not when running on its own window.  It's really frustrating when you're new to javascript lol